# Certificate failing on Load Balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53

I have purchased a domain from Amazon Route 53.

Also, I have created a new EC2 Instance.

I have created one Hosted Zone and configured DNS and domain routing.

I have also created an SSL certificate from the Certificate Manager, and created a Load Balancer to activate SSL.

But neither domain is start working and the certificate is not working. The only EC2 instance is working with an IP.

Any help regarding this would be appreciated.

```
earlyyearz.com. NS
   ns-1239.awsdns-26.org. 
   ns-54.awsdns-06.com. 
   ns-1748.awsdns-26.co.uk. 
   ns-1010.awsdns-62.net.

ec2-3-221-201-103.compute-1.amazonaws.com - - 172800

earlyyearz.com. SOA
   ns-1239.awsdns-26.org.

awsdns-hostmaster.amazon.com. 1 7200 900 1209600 86400 - - 900 www.earlyyearz.com
```

Comment: You have to most more details when you say "neither domain is start working and nor the certificate is working". What does it mean by not working? How did you configure R53 hosted zone/record set? What errors are you getting, etc.

Comment: earlyyearz.com.
NS
ns-1239.awsdns-26.org. 
ns-54.awsdns-06.com. 
ns-1748.awsdns-26.co.uk. 
ns-1010.awsdns-62.net. 
ec2-3-221-201-103.compute-1.amazonaws.com
-
-
172800
earlyyearz.com.
SOA
ns-1239.awsdns-26.org. awsdns-hostmaster.amazon.com. 1 7200 900 1209600 86400
-
-
900
www.earlyyearz.com.
A
3.221.201.103

Comment: Not getting any errors

Comment: http://www.earlyyearz.com/ but my domain is not working

Comment: it says site can'nt be reached

Comment: Please include a screenshot of your **Registered domains** screen and the **Hosted zones** screen. It is too hard to read the pasted values.

Comment: https://ibb.co/fXj6DPS  here is the link of snapshot

Comment: Have you tried to ping you domain from cmd? It should resolve to AWS ELB first.
If not, there is some issue with R53 configuration. If it is resolved but you are not able to access the application, check the routing from ELB to EC2 instances.

Comment: when I try ping it show something like this ping: http://www.earlyyearz.com/: Name or service not known

Comment: can you tell me what to do next.

Comment: the ns information from whois doesn't match your screen shot.  Your domain isn't resolving, this might be why?

Comment: @saurabh14292 today i tried ping earlyyearz.com and it was successful

Comment: @saurabh14292 but when I hit the site it says This site can’t be reached

Comment: ISSUE IS RESOLVED NOW. thanks to all

Comment: @Vorsprung  your comment saved my time. thank you

Answer (score 3):

I assume you have already done the things here
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/gs-acm-request-public.html

Next

1) remove the ec2 from the NS section of your DNS (probably doesn't matter but it's wrong)

2) follow instructions at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/using-domain-names-with-elb.html and alias the domain name associated with the certificate with the LB